# Site blocked by google

Tags: malware

I have my site that was hackered.
I have removed all files and reloaded clean old files without the hacked code.

Now when I use Google Chrome, I can't access my site because is shows as blocked.

How can I solve this?

If I go into webmastertools, it shows all is ok for it but not for google chrome.

Comment: Have you contacted Google Support?

Comment: According to Google's SafeBrowsing your site is still being blocked: http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=webanddesign.it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you requested Google to review your site? Just because you went into the tools to check, doesn't mean it will automatically remove the block.

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=168328

> However, if your site has been flagged as containing malware, filing a
>   reconsideration request isn't enough. You must follow the process on
>   this page to request a malware review.
>
> Google's automatic systems will scan your website. If no malware is
>   found, we'll remove the warning from your site. This may take a day or
>   so to happen; you can check the status of your request in Webmaster
>   Tools on the Malware page under Health.